# 302 редирект с http на https

Tags: http, joomla, redirect, https, редирект

В htaccess перенаправлений нет. Если поставить, например, такой код:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

то возникает циклическая переадресация.

В конфигурационном сайте

```
$force_ssl = '0';
$live_site = 'https://mydomen.google/';
```

В `/libraries/joomla/uri/uri.php` в первом же `if` метода `getInstance $https` в обоих случаях = `'s://'`

Там же в методе `base` есть такая строка: `$live_site = str_replace("http://", "https://", $config->get('live_site'));`

Есть ещё плагин `sh404SEF`, но я не знаю куда смотреть.

**Мне необходимо оставить https, но поменять редирект на 301.**

Я не силён в Джумле, так что, скорее всего, что-то забыл.